# Otter experience in Europe?

Tags: europe, nature-and-wildlife

Since I'm travelling through Europe, going through many countries, I've never seen in a zoo/Aquarium to have an "otter experience", so is there anywhere in Europe with anything like that?

My next trip is to the UK (London) and Portugal (roadtrip from Lisboa to Porto). Furthermore, this year I will be travelling also to Scotland, Austria, Germany, Croatia and possibly Spain/France too.

What is an otter experience? Well, it's an encounter with otters in a decent way, not to harm or do anything bad under supervision of zoo/Aquarium workers.

Somewhere you can swim with them, somewhere you can just approach the pools with otters.

[image]

Comment: The tag "animal-riding" is rather weird in the context of otters

Comment: There are plenty of wildlife parks where you can get pretty close to otters.  My guess would be that otters could get quite aggressive and have a nasty bite, so I'm not sure swimming with them is a great plan.

Comment: Agressive? I wouldn't say so. Wherever they keep them for encounters as such, I think they are quite friendly. Link below related.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMfYfoBxOV
PS: I'd prefer seaotters, but even the freshwater would be also great experience :)

Answer (score 4):

Edinburgh Zoo offers various ‘keeper experiences’ and has an otter enclosure. http://www.edinburghzoo.org.uk//events-and-experiences/keeper-experiences/

Comment: Great great great!! Thank you, will mark it down :)
Now just searching for any possibilities to find things as such in Portugal :)